# SwiftUI How to change background color of the view based on fetched data?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on a basic weather app on SwiftUI that dynamically changing the color depending on the weather status. Everything works perfectly fine, but I cannot send the OpenWeatherMap icon data that was parsed from JSON to my View. It looks like it doesn't allocate the info that was sent from another Swift file to the variable I declared. I have some experience with normal Swift but SwiftUI concepts are definitely not familiar.

Here is my ContentView.swift below.

```
   import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selected = 0
    @ObservedObject var weather = CurrentWeatherViewModel()
    @State var city : String = ""
    private var height : CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        var body: some View {
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    TextField("Enter your city", text: $city){
                    self.weather.fetchmetric(self.city)
                    }.padding(.horizontal)
                    
                }
                    GeometryReader{ gr in
                        CurrentWeather(weather: self.weather.current, height: self.selected == 0 ? gr.size.height : (gr.size.height*0.75)).frame(width: 375.0, height: 770).modifier(currentViewModifier()).animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5))
                    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    
            }.frame(width: 375, height: 735, alignment: .center)
            
        
            
        }
    }
```

This is my CurrentWeather.swift file. the @State color variable is the variable I need to change.

```
    import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct CurrentWeather: View {
    // Added color themes for potential weather scenarios
    let bgColors = [
        "Clear":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.6544341662, green: 0.9271220419, blue: 0.9764705896, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Sunny":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705896, green: 0.850980401, blue: 0.5490196347, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411793, green: 0.8685067713, blue: 0.1800223484, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Partly cloudy":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.5644291786, green: 0.6156922265, blue: 0.8125274491, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.3611070699, green: 0.3893437324, blue: 0.5149981027, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Cloudy":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.5088317674, green: 0.5486197199, blue: 0.7256778298, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.3843137255, green: 0.4117647059, blue: 0.5450980392, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Broken clouds":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.4714559888, green: 0.41813849, blue: 0.4877657043, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.3823538819, green: 0.3384427864, blue: 0.3941545051, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Mist":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.8536048541, green: 0.8154317929, blue: 0.6934956985, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.5, green: 0.3992742327, blue: 0.3267588525, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Patchy rain possible":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.422871705, green: 0.486337462, blue: 0.7241632297, alpha: 1)), Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.3826735404, green: 0.4012053775, blue: 0.9529411793, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Patchy snow possible":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.8229460361, green: 0.8420813229, blue: 0.9764705896, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.6424972056, green: 0.9015246284, blue: 0.9529411793, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Patchy sleet possible":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705896, green: 0.7979655136, blue: 0.9493740175, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.6843526756, green: 0.7806652456, blue: 0.9529411793, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Patchy freezing drizzle possible":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.6207757569, green: 0.9686274529, blue: 0.9110963382, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.4745098054, green: 0.8392156959, blue: 0.9764705896, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Thundery outbreaks possible":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.3647058904, green: 0.06666667014, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.5607843399, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Blowing snow":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.5607843399, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.09019608051, green: 0, blue: 0.3019607961, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Thunderstorm":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.9551106616, green: 0.9764705896, blue: 0.9351792135, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.6891936611, green: 0.7095901305, blue: 0.9529411793, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Fog":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.6324083141, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.7850640474, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.4545597353, green: 0.393878495, blue: 0.5369011739, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Freezing fog":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.4545597353, green: 0.393878495, blue: 0.5369011739, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Patchy light drizzle":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.5892893535, green: 0.7170531098, blue: 0.9764705896, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Light rain":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.2854045624, green: 0.4267300284, blue: 0.6992385787, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Moderate rain":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.3437546921, green: 0.6157113381, blue: 0.7179171954, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.4118283819, green: 0.5814552154, blue: 0.6975531409, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Heavy rain":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.4980392158, blue: 0.7568627596, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.1596036421, green: 0, blue: 0.5802268401, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Light freezing rain":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.7433765433, green: 0.9529411793, blue: 0.8886958889, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.4561494407, green: 0.6342332627, blue: 0.7568627596, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "Heavy rain at times":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.4980392158, blue: 0.7568627596, alpha: 1)), Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.1596036421, green: 0, blue: 0.5802268401, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom),
        "defaultStatus":LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9372549057, green: 0.3490196168, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1)),Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9686274529, green: 0.78039217, blue: 0.3450980484, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
    ]
    
    var weather : Weather?
    var height : CGFloat = 0
    
   @State var color : String = "defaultStatus"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
            Image(weather?.weather.last?.icon ?? "01d")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 130, height: 130)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            Text("Today in \(weather?.name ?? "Unknown")")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            .bold()
            .padding()
            HStack{
                Text("\(weather?.main.temp ?? 0)°")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .font(.system(size: 50))
               
            }
            Text("\(weather?.weather.last?.description ?? "Unknown")")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.body)
            
        }.frame(width: height, height: height)
            .background(bgColors[color])
            
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                NavigationLink(destination: Settings()) {
                                    Image(systemName: "gear").imageScale(.large).accentColor(.black)
                            })
        }.onAppear {} // Code Execution at startup
    }
}

struct currentViewModifier : ViewModifier{
    private var radius : CGFloat = 20
    private var xAxis : CGFloat = 20
    private var yAxis : CGFloat = 20
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .cornerRadius(radius)
            
            .opacity(1.0)
        
    }
}
```

This is my WeatherModel.swift file where I have functions to execute fetching and the background() function to make the code run.

```
    import Foundation
import Combine

final class CurrentWeatherViewModel : ObservableObject{
    @Published var current : Weather?
    
    init() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //if Settings().selected == 0{
                self.fetchmetric()
            //}
           // else{
                self.fetchimperial()
           // }
        }
    }
}

// fetch functions for metric and imperial and set color at the home screen

extension CurrentWeatherViewModel {
    func fetchmetric(_ city : String = "london"){
        let icon = current?.weather.last?.icon
        API.fetchCurrentmetricWeather(by: city) {
            // Work In Progress
            
            self.current = $0
            CurrentWeather().color = self.backgroundColor(code: icon ?? "aaa")
        }
    }
    
    func fetchimperial(_ city : String = "london"){
        API.fetchCurrentimperialWeather(by: city) {
            self.current = $0
            
        }
    }
    func backgroundColor(code : String) -> String {
        
        switch code {
            case "01d":
                return "Clear"
            case "02d":
                return "Partly cloudy"
            case "02n":
                return "Partly cloudy"
            case "03d":
                return "Cloudy"
            case "03n":
                return "Cloudy"
            case "04d":
                return "Broken clouds"
            case "04n":
                return "Broken clouds"
            case "09d":
                return "Moderate Rain"
            case "09n":
                return "Heavy rain"
            case "10d":
                return "Moderate Rain"
            case "10n":
                return "Heavy rain"
            case "11d":
                return "Thunderstorm"
            case "11n":
                return "Thunderstorm"
            case "13d":
                return "Snow"
            case "13n":
                return "Snow"
            case "50d":
                return "Mist"
            case "50n":
                return "Mist"
            default:
                return "defaultStatus"
            }
        }
        
}
```

My question is, what am I missing that it does not send the icon data to the CurrentWeather color variable? I must say I am unfamiliar with @State variables and trying to learn SwiftUI.

Appreciate any Input on the code.

Answer (score 1):

The expression
`CurrentWeather().color = self.backgroundColor(code: icon ?? "aaa")` is senseless, because modifies locally created value (`CurrentWeather()` creates struct value).

Instead you need to create published property in view model for color and use it, like

```
final class CurrentWeatherViewModel : ObservableObject{
    @Published var current : Weather?
    @Publisehd var color: String = "aaa"
```

then update it as

```
API.fetchCurrentmetricWeather(by: city) { weather in
    // Work In Progress
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async { // update published on main queue !!!
       self.current = weather
       self.color = self.backgroundColor(code: icon ?? "aaa")
    }
}
```

then use it in view like

```
    }.frame(width: height, height: height)
        .background(bgColors[self.weather?.color ?? "defaultStatus"])
```

and local view `@State var color` not needed

Comment: Thank you for your input. As I put the code as you instructed I am recieving "Contextual closure type '@convention(block) () -> Void' expects 0 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body" on the DispatchQueue line.

Comment: `self.weather?.color` doesnt seem to be existing, I used `bgColors[self.model?.color ?? "defaultStatus"]` as I assumed you meant CurrentWeatherViewModel. The code works fine, but it still gets the default input.